# Can you set the text of an autocomplete?

Tags: javascript

Let's say i have an element like the foregoing:

```
<input id="userName">
```

Is it possible to set an autocomplete string and then do:

```
document.getElementById('userName').autocomplete = true;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible directly, but there is a hack for that... like this:

```html
<form>
   <input list="autocomplete_list" name="my_input" />
   <datalist id="autocomplete_list">
       <option value="hello">
       <option value="hi">
       <option value="what's up">
   </datalist>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your provided solution. Care to elaborate? Surely there's some in browser way to do this. Like from an extension maybe?

Comment: I don't understand. You wanted to change the autocomplete list, not an autocomplete plugin. You can't change the build-in browser autocomplete list ANY WAY. And this autocomplete solution works fine, so why do you need third parties? There are LOTS of autocomplete javascript scripts, the most used is jQuery UI one... https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ , but what is wrong with that solution? Simple, clean, no JS needed at all.

Comment: I'm just trying to understand the above. What would this even achieve? What does autocomplete_list do exactly? I'm trying to make a function that sends text to forms on webpages using autocomplete rather than .value. I have my reasons for wanting to do this.

Comment: it makes custom autocomplete list, the list is defined in datalist; if you are tying to send autocomplete instead of value, then maybe you should be more precise in your question? and no, you can't send autocomplete saved data, it would be a great security risk

Comment: well whats interesting to me is that for example. if you go to facebook and have autocomplete enabled for the login. the forms are filled with the text. and itll submit. this interests me because you cant login to facebook using .value and .click the form expects actual keyboard input. so i thought itd be interesting to use autocomplete where .value fails but i guess its not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can modify HTML attributes by element.setAttribute function.
`document.getElementById('userName').setAttribute("autocomplete", 'on')`